# JQuery CSS Images folder

Tags: jquery, css

I downloaded jQuery, I put the CSS into it's own folder, where does the images folder have to be located relative to that folder?

Comment: what does this question has to do with jQuery?

Comment: Are you talking about jQuery UI?

Comment: Images linked within the CSS file should have paths relative to that CSS file.

Comment: yes I am referring to jQuery UI

Comment: The images should be a folder named `images` inside the same folder as the CSS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is then the images should be placed in a folder `images` relative to the location of the css file.

ie: if the css file is kept in a folder called `css` then the images should be kept in `css/images`

Comment: I did that but the prev and nex buttons of the datepicker not showing.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer to your question :: put it inside your css folder

```
css/images
```

Comment: in(side) out(side) in(side) out(side) shake it all about, you minimize your windows and you give a shout - that's what this is all about! HEY!